# backbone.js empty models array d {models: Array[0], length: 0, _byId: Object, constructor: function, model: function…}

Tags: javascript, arrays, backbone.js

My collection is empty but contains my arrays. I want to perform a where on the collection, but this is not possible as d models returns an array[0]. So the data is not pushed there.

I guess it's because my data is generated asynchrone

d {models: Array[0], length: 0, _byId: Object, constructor: function, model: function…}
_byId: Object
_events: Object
_idAttr: "id"
_listenerId: "l4"
length: 15
models: Array[15]
**proto**: e

from app.js

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "Onderwerpen": "subjectsList"

    },

    initialize: function  () {

        this.categories = new Categories();
        this.categories.getCategoriesFromJSON();

        console.log(this.categories);


        //view for subjectsList
        this.subjectsListView = new SubjectsListView({collection: this.categories});


    },



    subjectsList: function () {
        $('#app').html(this.subjectsListView.render().el);
    },   

});

var app = new AppRouter();

$(function() {
    Backbone.history.start();
});
```

from categories.js

```
var Categories = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model : Category,
getCategoriesFromJSON : function(){


    var self = this,
        categories = [];

    $.ajax({
        url      : './catalogue.json',
        dataType : 'json'
    }).done(function(data){

        console.log('Catalogue retrieved');

        _.each(data.categories, function( categorieObj ){

            var categorieName       = _.keys(categorieObj)[0],
                categorieAttributes = categorieObj[categorieName];

            categories.push( categorieAttributes );

        });

        //console.log(JSON.stringify(categories));

        self.add( categories );
        self.trigger('reset');
    });
}


});
```

what's going wrong?

Comment: I'm listening to it in my view function: var SubjectsListView = Backbone.View.extend({
 initialize: function  () {
  this.listenTo(this.collection, "reset", this.render);
 },

I will have a look at collection#reset and collection#parse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a proper solution. Before starting the backbone app I'm retrieving the JSON data in a new function loadDataAndStartApp(). This function is loaded when the dom is ready, and once the JSON is loaded it starts the backbone app. This way you are certain to have all the data available.

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
routes: {
    "": "startscreen",
    "Onderwerpen": "subjectsList", //show list of subjects: eg Evenwicht, Zien & horen, etc
},

initialize: function  (options) {


    this.categories = new Categories( options.categories );


    this.subjectsListView2 = new SubjectsListView({
        collection: new Categories(
            this.categories.where({ parent : null, name : "Evenwicht" })
        )
    });

    //view for spacesList



},

startscreen: function () {
    $('#app').html(this.startscreenView.render().el);
},

subjectsList: function () {
    $('#app').append(this.subjectsListView2.render().el);
},

});

function loadDataAndStartApp(){

var categories     = [],
    category_trees = [];

// LOAD APP DATA
$.ajax({

    url      : './catalogue.json',
    dataType : 'json'

}).done(function(data){

    console.log('Catalogue retrieved');

    // GET CATEGORIES
    _.each(data.categories, function( categorieObj ){

        var categorieName       = _.keys(categorieObj)[0],
            categorieAttributes = categorieObj[categorieName];

        categories.push( categorieAttributes );

    });

    // START APP
    var app = new AppRouter({ 
        categories     : categories,
        category_trees : category_trees
    });

    Backbone.history.start();
});
}


$(function(){
// ON DOM READY

loadDataAndStartApp();
});
```